# Bulk change the order of attributes dropdowns on WooCommerce variable products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, dropdown, custom-taxonomy

I have 2 product attributes on my products: **color** and **size**. They are rendered in that order. I need to switch them, so that size always comes first.

The WooCommerce file `single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php` seems responsible for the output, but I am not skilled enough to suggest a change to this code, that would make it order by `attribute_id`, `attribute_name`, or reverse default order. Right now they seem to order by a taxonomy term or slug rather than actual attribute data, changing ID or name of attributes in the `woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies` table does not help.

Please help me crack this.

I have searched for this without luck, the answer might be hidden among the many questions about attribute term order which is NOT what I am asking here.

EDIT: I have thousands of products, so manual per-product reordering won't work.

```
$attribute_keys = array_keys( $attributes );

do_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form' ); ?>

<form class="variations_form cart" action="<?php echo esc_url( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_form_action', $product->get_permalink() ) ); ?>" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data' data-product_id="<?php echo absint( $product->get_id() ); ?>" data-product_variations="<?php echo htmlspecialchars( wp_json_encode( $available_variations ) ); // WPCS: XSS ok. ?>">
    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_variations_form' ); ?>

    <?php if ( empty( $available_variations ) && false !== $available_variations ) : ?>
        <p class="stock out-of-stock"><?php esc_html_e( 'This product is currently out of stock and unavailable.', 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>
    <?php else : ?>
        <table class="variations" cellspacing="0">
            <tbody>
                <?php foreach ( $attributes as $attribute_name => $options ) : ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="label"><label for="<?php echo esc_attr( sanitize_title( $attribute_name ) ); ?>"><?php echo wc_attribute_label( $attribute_name ); // WPCS: XSS ok. ?></label></td>
                        <td class="value">
                            <?php
                                wc_dropdown_variation_attribute_options( array(
                                    'options'   => $options,
                                    'attribute' => $attribute_name,
                                    'product'   => $product,
                                ) );
                                echo end( $attribute_keys ) === $attribute_name ? wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_reset_variations_link', '<a class="reset_variations" href="#">' . esc_html__( 'Clear', 'woocommerce' ) . '</a>' ) ) : '';
                            ?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** *(related to your edit)*

Is not possible to alter this using code, as it's handle by [`WC_Product_Variable_Data_Store_CPT`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/3.5.0/includes/data-stores/class-wc-product-variable-data-store-cpt.php) Class on [`read_variation_attributes()`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/3.5.0/includes/data-stores/class-wc-product-variable-data-store-cpt.php#L157-L225) method and there is no available hook(s) for that.

Also as that data is cached, a filter hook should not be reasonably welcome..

In general your actual problem doesn't occurs for most people, as they set a sorting from start on each product, when adding attributes to a variable product.

Now you could try to change that, on the database, but it seems not possible as the product attributes sorting is based on the index of **a serialized array** located in `wp_postmeta` for a variable product `post_id` using the `meta_key = _product_attributes`.

---

**Original answer:**

In a Variable product settings, under "Product data" *(metabox)* > Attributes *(tab)*, you can add product attributes. You can also reorder them simply **dragging and drop them** on the desired positions.

[image]

This will affect the order of the product attributes dropdown, in front end, for a variable product. So you don't need any code for that.

> **In database**, the product attributes sorting is based on the index of an array located in `wp_postmeta` for a variable product `post_id` using the `meta_key = _product_attributes`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I did not occur to me to mention why I can't do a manual reordering: I have thousands of products. A code solution would therefore be preferable.

Comment: @prokops I have updated my answer… It's not possible to crack that using code. Only may be, making a complex function that will update progressively your related variable products could solve that *(but it's a real specific development)*.